# Solving a differential equation with trigonometric functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

How could I approach 
$$\displaystyle y - A\cdot \sin\biggl(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\biggr) = 0\;?$$

Comment: If initial values are given you can apply $\sin^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $s=y’$.

Then, 
$$y=A\sin\frac{ds}{dx}=A\sin\frac{ds}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=A\sin s\frac{ds}{dy}$$

Rearranging yields 
$$sds=dy\sin^{-1}\frac yA$$

You should finally obtain 
$$\sqrt2 x+C_2=\int dy\left(y\sin^{-1}\frac yA+A\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{A^2}}+C_1\right)^{-1/2}$$

The integral can be rewritten into
$$A\int\frac{\cos g}{\sqrt{C_1+A(g\sin g+\cos g)}}dg$$ by letting $y=A\sin g$.

I do not expect the integral is elementary.